# Google Maps API: Change marker animation speed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

**Google Maps API v3** currently supports two types of **animation** for **markers**: DROP and BOUNCE

Is there a way I can **speed up** the BOUNCE or **slow down** the DROP animation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Maps API doesn't support animation properties or customization, just the ability to select "drop" or "bounce" as you said.

It should be possible to apply custom animations to marker elements through jQuery or other framework. Alternatively you could supply an animated GIF as a marker.